# Getting ClientContext by guid

Tags: guid

If I understand correctly , each SP site has it's own 128 bit generated unique id.
Is it possible, in CSOM, to do something like:

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext('128-bit-generated-id');
```

Or anything equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's is not possible. The only ways to do this are:

1. ClientContext(String) - Initializes a new instance of the
   ClientContext class for the SharePoint site with the specified
   absolute URL.
2. ClientContext(Uri) - Initializes a new instance of the ClientContext
   class for the site with the specified Uri object.

[Link to source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext.clientcontext.aspx)

**But you can use [Site.OpenWebById()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/Library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.site.openwebbyid.aspx) and get web by GUID**

Answer (score 0):

i think this is not possible bcz there is no options available for guid in parameter values

[image]

[image: Here is no options available for guid in parameter values]

you need to provide full url as a stirng or Uri form

Example for pass url as a string format

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("full web url");
```

Example for pass url a Uri format

```
Uri uri=new Uri("web full url")
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(Uri);
```

Comment: A much easier way to check it would be checking the documentation, instead of asking the IDE to auto-complete a piece of code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext.clientcontext.aspx#Overload%C2%A0list